# Check if row values match in an ACF Repeater

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF repeater with several rows.

I need to check if all the `$distance` values are over 100.

```
<?php if( have_rows('store') ): ?>
  <?php while( have_rows('store') ): the_row();

    $distance = get_sub_field('distance'); ?>

    <?php echo $distance; ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making an array and then check with `min`.

```
<?php if( have_rows('store') ): $distances = array(); ?>
  <?php while( have_rows('store') ): the_row();

    $distance = get_sub_field('distance'); ?>
    $distances[] = $distance;

    <?php if (min($distances) >= 100) { echo 'all over 100'; } ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```